# Best way to generate Ansible documentation

Tags: ansible-2.x

I'd like to generate documentation pages about the hosts I manage with Ansible, and upload them to a web server.

What would be the best, non-hacky way of achieving this?

I want the HTML template to list IP addresses of hosts, and the values of many hostvars.

I noticed that when I run my inventory script, many of these variables are listed under _meta hostvars, but all the jinja expressions are non interpolated: i.e. the "{{expressions}}" are not expanded out.

I'm finding that because I'm executing the role to generate the documentation on the web server host only, many of these variables are not available in the template.

For example the IP addresses of other hosts are not available, and fail with: 'dict object' has no attribute 'ansible_default_ipv4'

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable fact caching https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/cache.html
2. Execute `setup` module on every host in question
3. Collect required information from fact cache with some script